# Facebook Graph API How to pull a list of all events a friend is attending

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm trying to use the Facebook Graph API to pull a list of events friends of the user are attending, here is the API Documentation:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/events

If I put in:
`me/events`
it works, but if I put in `193300913/events` it returns nothing.

`193300913` is the id of a random friend, I've tried with several other friends with which I should have the right permissions to see all of they events they are attending, but it returns nothing for everyone.

What am I missing?

Also here are the permissions being requested:

`$permissions = array(scope=>'user_events,user_friends');`

Answer (score 0):

That´s not possible, since friend permissions are deprecated for privacy reasons: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

I would not want any App to get access to my events if i did not even authorize the App, just because a friend of mine is using it.